# When M is negative one should prefer $\sqrt{|M|}$ to $\sqrt{-M}$. Right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For otherwise we get $\sqrt{-M}=\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{M}$ but the terms on the right are meaningless.

Comment: If $M<0$, then $|M|=-M$ and therefore $\sqrt{|M|}=\sqrt{-M}$.

Comment: $\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{M}$ is fine (using complex numbers).

Comment: In addition, we don’t have that $\sqrt{ab}= \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ when dealing with negative $a$ or $b$ unless we’d like to work with complex numbers, and even in that situation, that equality doesn’t always hold.

Comment: @Dave It's not quite fine. For example,if $M=-1$ then to get the desired $\sqrt1=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}$ you have to interpret one occurrence of $\sqrt{-1}$ as $i$ and the other as $-i$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you do not have a definition for the string of symbols "$\sqrt{-1}$", since you call that term meaningless.  Consequently, your current identities for manipulating square roots must already exclude the idea.  (Otherwise, you can have such nonsense as
$  1 = \sqrt{1} = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} = -1  $ .)
In fact, your identity should be something like "if $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$, then $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$."  Whenever there are conditions on a rewriting rule, the conditions have to be met to apply the rule.  You are applying the rule to $a = -1 < 0$ and $b = M < 0$, so not all conditions are satisfied and you cannot apply the rule.

Generally, if you do not have a definition for "$\sqrt{-1}$", it definitely should not appear in your work.  Much as you do not have a definition for "$\sqrt{\div}$", so that sequence of symbols also should not appear in your work.

Finally, for $M < 0$, $-M = |M|$.  (Recall that absolute value is defined piecewise and the piece for negative $M$s *is* "$-M$".)  Consequently, both $\sqrt{-M}$ and $\sqrt{|M|}$ represent the same value, so they are interchangeable.  Which one you should prefer depends on what aspect you wish to emphasize.  Much like the difference between "*I* went to the store." and "I went to the *store*.", both versions have the same plain meaning, but emphasize different aspects of what is happening.  If you do not have a definition for square roots of negative numbers, "$\sqrt{-M}$" emphasizes that $M < 0$, since otherwise the expression is undefined, and "$\sqrt{|M|}$" emphasizes that you do not care about the sign of $M$ and are ensuring that it is a valid thing to take a square root of.  I.e., one emphasizes the need to "fix" the sign of $M$ and one emphasizes not caring about the sign of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

If $M$ is negative, then $\sqrt M$ actually has no meaning, since the operation $\sqrt{}$ by definition takes *nonnegative* inputs, and returns (nonnegative) *real* values.

Thus, with $M<0,$ we have that $-M$ is positive, so that it is $$\sqrt{(-M)}$$ that is well-defined here. Also, of course, $\sqrt{(|M|)}$ is properly defined since $|\cdot|\ge 0$ for all arguments.